# How to create assets for unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I know I can create all the colliders as game objects but I am unable to understand how to create assets such as wall colors, chairs, cars, etc. What software do I need to use make these? Is blender used for creating these or something else?

Comment: This appears to be off-topic for this site (perhaps http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ may be a better fit). But yes, tools such as Blender, 3DS Max, Maya, etc. are used to create the 3D models, while tools such as Photoshop, Gimp, etc. are used to create the textures.

Comment: I mainly use Blender(free) and Gimp(free)/Photoshop/Paint Shop Pro

Comment: Thank you @ssell and vba4all. I wanted to know exactly that.

Answer (score 7):

free 3D modeling software: Blender, (Free version) Sketchup, (Student version) 3Ds Max or Maya
free 2D art software: GIMP 2.x

Comment: Thank you. Why has this been downvoted?